# RSS feed link not opening

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm parsing an RSS feed and storing each item in a dictionary and each one of these in an array.  This all works fine, but when I try and open a link from the feed nothing happens, the URL appears to be correct as I have NSLogged it when pressing the button, I have remove whitespace, newlines and tabs from the URL, but am unsure weather I have done this correctly.  Any Ideas?

I know the initial parsing and storage is fine as I am using other elements in other parts of the program so I will just show the code directly involved with the problem.

Formatting the URL

```
libraryRSSString = [[stories objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"link"];
[libraryRSSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"   " withString:@""];
[libraryRSSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

and the action for opening the link, I will mention now that the action works when hardcoding the link, as in @"http://www.google.com";

```
-(IBAction)LibraryRSSAction{

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:libraryRSSString]];

       NSLog(@"button pressed");

       NSLog(@"the link is %@",libraryRSSString);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encoding the url in a wrong way, try [this](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios).

**EDIT (To include the code on the link above):**

Create a category named "NSString+URLEncoding", files NSString+URLEncoding.h and NSString+URLEncoding.m.

**NSString+URLEncoding.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
@end
```

**NSString+URLEncoding.m:**

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
               (CFStringRef)self,
               NULL,
               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
@end
```

Now import the file NSString+URLEncoding.h on the file you want to use the method and just do `libraryRSSString = [[[stories objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"link"] urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Thanks, looks promising although when I call the method I get a warning saying 'NSString may not respond to urlEncodeUsingEncoding', tried compiling it anyway and its leads to a SIGBART when the button is pressed

Comment: Have you imported the category?

Answer (score 0):

The links should have http:// as prefix to be able to be opened. The URL you are getting may not have the http prefix. google.com worked because it had http:// prefix.

Comment: Vut he's still encoding the URL in a wrong way, you don't just remove spaces, you encode them.

Comment: The link is a complete URL including the http:// prefix and will work when hard coded, can I ask if there is standard way to encode a URL?